# How does one get the width of an absolute/fixed element with jquery/js, on resize?

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize

Lets say you have a fixed or absolute positioned element:

```
<div>
   My fixed div.
</div>
```

With the following css:

```
div:first-of-type {
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

You can figure out the width via:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var $myFixedDiv = $('div:first');

        console.log($myFixedDiv.width()); //$myFixedDiv.innerWidth(), $myFixedDiv.outerWidth() 
    });

});
```

However, when you resize the window, the width reported by both firefox and chrome is 0.

How would one figure out what the true width is?

Comment: Your code looks good, are you using the newest version of jquery??

Comment: I am using jquery 1.5.1, I guess I could pull 1.5.2?

Comment: It works fine for me in Firefox 4 and Chrome 10 (using jquery 1.5.1).

Answer (score 2):

You could take the window's width and minus 40 from both axis.

```
var width = $(window).width()-40;
var height = $(window).height()-40;
```

Then rather than using the css top, left, bottom and right to set the width as I think will be unreliable in the long term I would set the div's width with the js

```
var myDiv = $('#myDiv');
myDiv.width = width;
myDiv.height = height;
```

Comment: position left and right after resize, is giving 0s on firefox and chrome seems to be giving me an incorrect value.

Comment: chrome is giving me the right values after i removed underscore.js debounce. firefox still doesn't work.